# Write file with C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to write a file but It doesn't work. This is my sample code.

```
ofstream file ("file.txt");

if (file.is_open()){
    file << "Write 1 line.\n";
    file << "Write 2 line.\n";
    file.close();
    cout << "Successfull" << endl;
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

I'm doing the fstream import and creating the txt file into the main.cpp folder.

Comment: The working directory may differ from "the main.cpp folder". What is your environment (IDE?)?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Explain what's happening.

Comment: I'm using XCODE. The file is always empty.

Comment: Try writing `std::endl` to it at the end of line 2 and don't call `close()`, RAII does that for you.

Comment: Which message are you seeing being output: `Successfull` or `Unable to open file`? If the former, make sure the file is created where you are expecting. Always use absolute paths, not relative paths.

Comment: The console show the cout messages but the file is always empty. Sombrero Chicken, It doesnt work that you say, I use the namespace std.

Comment: Did you edit your schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem, XCODE create the files here:

/Users/[name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[projectname]/Build/Product/Debug